# Car accelerating very quickly

Tags: toyota, camry, acceleration

I bought an used car of 2011  make camry, which is in good condition.

The car is accelerating too quickly, even for a little gas and it's jumping with out a smooth move.

I am afraid to put my foot on the pedal, as even for a little / tiny push on the gas pedal is making a big move on the car. I want to reduce its very quick rapid moment.

I have visited an auto shop near to our location but they said so many tests to do to identify the problem. Any help... Thank you.

Comment: Questions on driving technique tend to get closed.

Comment: @solar, i would like to know about any known causes which makes a car accelerate rapidly but not about driving.

Comment: I believe that model uses a "fly-by-wire" accelerator pedal.  By that I mean there is no direct mechanical linkage between the accelerator and the throttle plate.  So you might have development a problem in the pedal position sensor itself.  It looks to be a fairly expensive item so you'll likely want to test it some before buying a new one.

Comment: @SolarMike - Reread the question. This isn't about how to drive, the question is about an apparent malfunction as to when the car accelerates. Not a driving question, IMHO.

Comment: Repeating- it is a "drive by wire" , the position of the throttle ( not the pressure) governs acceleration. You need to adjust driving habits.

Comment: @blacksmith37 It's not necessarily anything to do with the driver. I used to have a car where in certain weather conditions, the ECU decided on its own to increase the idle RPM from 700 to about 1800 part way through the engine warming up cycle. In a low gear that could produce a sharp acceleration from say 10 to 20 mph with my foot completely off the gas pedal.

Comment: If it has a Sport mode, turn it Off, see if it behaves differently.

Comment: @blacksmith37 accelerator pedals have always been position dependant not pressure dependant.  The driver shouldn't be able to tell if it is a mechanical linkage or electronic.

Comment: Is the check engine light on? Many times if the sensors for throttle position will cause a code if they don't correspond with each other or with the ECM. TPS is the only thing that comes to mind for this.

Comment: Both position dependent , but with linkage rods, cables , return springs , you get more resistance and "feel" with mechanical  than drive by wire. Usually when someone new drove my 2004 Titan there would be a few fast starts, not many drive by wire vehicles at that time.

Comment: get help reading any error codes https://www.autocodes.com/p0122_2011_toyota_camry.html

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Ask a friend to drive the car and get their opinion on how it accelerates. This will tell you if there is an objective issue with the car or you are just unfamiliar with it.
2. Contact the seller and ask them this question. Especially if your friend confirmed that there is something wrong with the car, ask the seller if they know how to fix the problem and try to avoid implying that you are going to go after the seller for the cost of repair.